# FusionPBX Creating SIP trunk or Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, fusionpbx

I have created fusionpbx instance using aws. Able to do internal calls between two extensions created. Now i would like to make external call to VOIP server when a particular extension is dialed. To do this i understand that we need to create a **sip trunk** between two machines i.e fusionpbx server and Voip server.

As of now i created a gateway without using username and password and added external Voip server ip address in CIDR block. But still cant start the gateway and it just refreshes page. No host name is given while configuring.

I have referred many documents available over internet but couldn't find any proper reference. Appreciate if anyone can help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out, i am posting here so that it may help for someone facing same issue.

By changing config key **Profile** value from *external* to *internal* resolved this issue for me.

Key points here to note while configuring gateway is, keep **Register** to *false* and if it kept false then don't give any `username` and `password`, leave those fields blank. Configure proxy address as shown in below reference and don't forget to add and allow access control (`CIDR` is your `voip server` address) under advanced settings of fusionpbx.

Here is the screenshot of gateway configuration for reference.
[image: fusionpbx gateway configuration]